SignalR can't connect wss with .NET Aspire?
We have an application that has Vue 3 frontend, a BFF (.NET8) and a backend API (.NET8 WebApi). The API has a SignalR message hub and sends messages to the Vue client. We've used Project Tye to run this solution locally with great success, and now we wanted to migrate to Aspire. The migration went well, all the components runs fine and works together, except that the SignalR client stopped receiving messages. It seems to connect to the hub. The "negotiate" call (https) gets a response, but the next call using wss never gets a response. Is there something special in the Aspire Host I need to setup to enable the WSS protocol?


Might be because of the proxy in between: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/aspire/fundamentals/networking-overview

Do you have any code you could share? I might be able to help.
